# Data Model for Appointments - choose multiple dates

Tags: java, c#, database, datetime

I am working on a problem which looks like this:

Imagine a doctor's office, where a client can make an appointment at let's say 4pm.

Imagine another client who wanted to go the doctor's at 4pm, but because it is taken, he has to go at 5pm.

Now imagine the possibility for the second client to ADDITIONALLY choose 4pm as a potential DateTime for the visit, so that when the first client decides not to come, the second client gets a notification saying: Hey you can come in earlier.

---

Client #1 opens app, selects date for appointment, e.g. 23rd May 2015.

- A page with services opens up, client #1 selects 'medical checkup' + 'blood test'.
- Another page opens with available hours that day (with consideration for the duration of both services).
- Client #1 select 4pm.

Client #2 opens app, selects the same date.

- A page with services opens up, client #2 select 'medical lookup'.
- The page with available hours opens up. Client #2 chooses both 4pm and 5pm.

Next,

- Client #1 opens app, cancels appointment for 4pm.
- Client #2 gets notification saying that appointment at 4pm is available.

---

I am trying to create a simple datamodel for this, but the multiple DateTimes for one appointment are killing me.

This is what I have right now:

Tables:

```
Client
int id
string name

Service // Bloodtest, General medical checkup, etc.
int id
string title
int duration // estimated duration in minutes

Appointment
int id
int client_id
int doctor_id
List<Service> Services
List<DateTime> AppointmentDateTimes

Doctor
int id
string name
List<Service> Services
```

My problem with the

```
List<DateTime>
```

approrach is, that I don't know which client has priority over the selected DateTime (who was first) and which DateTime of these the client prefers.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you want to tag this for java and c#? You could have every date have a Queue.

Comment: Can more than one service be performed during one appointment?

Comment: Yes, that's why there is a List of Services. Later the durations are added, and considered, when selecting available hours for a new appointment.

Comment: In my opinion you need finer granularity of your entities. Design DB first and then go for application. Good design takes all factors into account at the beginning, adding things later without considering them initially can cause problems and need to redesign

Comment: Actually, that's why I'm here, I need a kickstart with my DB design. :) I don't know how to model an actual appointment and apppointments with only preferred DateTimes..

Comment: EDIT your question, describe all functions and dependencies between data, tell a story of how the system works and let's start from there.

Comment: There is many to many relationship between APPOINTMENT and CLIENT. You need additional entity in between, with composite key inherited from both client and appointment APPOINTMENT_SERVICE

Comment: It would also help tremendously if certain amount of services could be done during one appointment, for example appointment lasts 20 minutes and one service takes 10 minutes

Comment: Hi Suspended, I have edited my question with how a potential usecase would look like. I would appreciate it if you'd take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make your appointment date times, which are currently just DateTime values, top-level objects. Each AppointmentDateTime object then has an ordered list of patients. Patient in the first place is the one booked, patients in place 2 or higher are on the wait list.

Additionally, each AppointmentDateTime object can have information like assigned doctor, room, etc. You will be able to have multiple AppointmentDateTime objects for the same time slot, each for a different doctor.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't think there is a usable object like Queue in databases (MS SQL).Could you elaborate on how a queue could be implemented using a database?

Comment: Editing time for my previous comment timed out... Let's say you have the following three tables and columns: AppointmentDateTime (id, doctor_id, start_time, end_time, room_id), Client (id, name), Appointment (id, appointment_date_time_id, client_id, service_id). The Appointment is essentially a mapping table between clients and appointment slots (represented through the AppointmentDateTime table). Add an "order" column to the Appointment table. The first client that registers gets 0 in that column, the next client gets 1. This way you can maintain the order of the appointment registrations.